# ¿ Como instanciar un objeto webservice asmx?

Tags: asp.net, webservice

En Visual Studio 2008 para consumir un webService con un método que se llama HelloWorld y devuelve un string desde codebehind lo instanciaba de la siguiente manera:

```
wsService1.Service miWs = new wsService1.Service();
```

Para Visual 2017 no encuentro la manera de instanciarlo ya que el método Service no me aparece.

Me da estas opciones:

```
wsService1.HelloWorldRequest
wsService1.HelloWorldRequestBody
wsService1.HelloWorldResponse
wsService1.HelloWorldResponseBody
wsService1.WebService1Soap
wsService1.WebService1SoapChanel
wsService1.WebService1SoapClient
```

¿ Como debo coger el parámetro string que me devuelve el webservice ?

Comment: Estás seguro de haber referenciado bien el webservice? Ten en cuenta que si es un asmx, debes ir a "agregar referencia de servicio", "avanzadas", "agregar referencia web"

Comment: Si, esta bien referenciado. ¿ Para que sirven entonces las diferentes opciones que puedes elegir y cual es la que debería elegir para instanciar ?

Comment: En ese caso, revisa el ws, porque se hace igual en 2017 que en 2008: `nombreReferenciaWeb.nombreWebservice ws = new nombreReferenciaWeb.nombreWebservice();`

Comment: Si vas a "agregar referencia web" como te he dicho, no hay ninguna opcion para elegir, solo introducir la url del servicio

Comment: Al final me ha funcionado instanciando como wsService1.WebService1SoapClient(). Pero no entiendo muy bien para que son las otras opciones

Comment: Creo que no es la manera correcta de llamar a un WebService mira este link https://forums.asp.net/t/1061559.aspx te va a ayudar a entender a como hacer el llamado a estos.

Comment: Gracias, por lo que veo hay 2 maneras de consumir servicios usando soap o rest